# How to understand what causes Truncated incorrect double value error in MySQL Function?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table which contains child-parent relationship in the following form:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | nParent   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         0 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         3 |
|  5 |         3 |
|  6 |         4 |
+----+-----------+
```

This table represents a tree (multi-level, n-ary) relationship among the objects I want to abstract. Rest of the application already uses this hierarchy and it's very easy to get parent of a child or children of a parent. However I'm now trying to solve a problem where I need all the elements in the subtree under a node. While searching for answers, I found an [amazing solution on DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161) that creates a function exactly for this requirement. Here's my code after the necessary modifications:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetFamilyTree`(GivenID INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

SET rv = '';
SET queue = GivenID;
SET queue_length = 1;

WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
    SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
    IF queue_length = 1 THEN
        SET queue = '';
    ELSE
        SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) +1 ;
        SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
        SET queue = q;
    END IF;
    SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

    SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
    FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) qc
    FROM nodes WHERE nParent = front_id) A;

    IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue_length = 0;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
            SET rv = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
    END IF;
END WHILE;

RETURN rv;

END
```

However when I run it, I get an error saying
**Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value '14,15,16'***

I rewrote the function part-by-part and individual segments (queries etc) work well. But in the function, it throws the error.

What might be wrong?
How can I find exactly what is causing the error?

Comment: Your possibly trying to compare a string to a number and automatic conversion is complaining.

Comment: The only place I can see where you might be trying to use a comma-separated string as a number is in the line `SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);` What happens if you cast `queue` as `unsigned` first i.e. `SET front_id = FORMAT(CAST(queue AS UNSIGNED),0);`?

Comment: @Nick no change in the error.

Comment: Any chance you can post sufficient data to replicate the problem on an SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Nick thanks for the suggestion. Created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ab951/1 

Wondering if stored functions work in sqlfiddle - but schema is ready

Comment: @Aditya I was right about the problem line, wrong about the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
```

`queue` is a comma-separated list of values, and MySQL doesn't want to convert it to a numeric value. Changing this line to

```
SET front_id = cast(substring_index(queue, ',', 1) as unsigned);
```

solves the problem. See this [demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/GJQHJ31721) where you can try changing between the two lines of code.